# What loud thunder! or What a loud thunder!

Tags: grammar, articles, sentence-structure, british-english, spoken-english

My reference book gives me an example as follows:

> **What loud thunder!**

Should it be written as:

> *What **a** loud thunder!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the entry for thunder from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/thunder):

> thunder noun UK ​  /ˈθʌn.dər/ US ​  /ˈθʌn.dɚ/
>   B1 [**U**] the sudden loud noise that comes from the sky especially during a storm

Note the **U**, which indicates that thunder is uncountable. Uncountable nouns don't generally require an indefinite article, unless you are talking about a particular type of whatever it is, for example:

> This is a really nice cheese

... meaning this is a really nice **type** of cheese.

So, with thunder, you would generally omit the indefinite article

> What loud thunder!

unless you are referring to a particular kind of thunder, but I can't think of a suitable example of that.

Comment: I might use thunderclap to reference a specific instance of thunder in a thunderstorm. "Wow that was a loud thunderclap"

Comment: I'd argue the Alps one, you wouldn't have the 'a' in there unless the 'type of' was in there. *They have **a** really loud thunder* on its own does not sound right. *They have really loud thunder* would be more idiomatic

Comment: @smock, agreed... I have removed that example.